# Resource result ensure throughout application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have index.html

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <nav ng-show="items" mm-menu>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

defined Controllers

```
MainCtrl($rootScope, MyResource) {
    var p = function() { 
        return MyResource.query().$promise;
    };
    p().then(function(data){
        $rootScope.items = data;
    });
}

SomeCtrl($rootScope){
    var myItems = $rootScope.items;
    // myItems undefined
    myItems[0].name
}
```

and state

```js
$stateProvider.state('somestate', function() {
    //....
    url: '/something/:id',
    controller: 'SomeCtrl'
});
```

`mm-menu` is just a directive for jQuery.

In `SomeCtrl` `items` aren't always available at the moment of html render, because of resource load, but some values are always returned from resource. How do I go about sharing some top resource data with **all controllers and states** after resource has returned?

- Is abstract state a way to go?
- Or should I use requireJS?
- Maybe angular-data?
- Manual bootstrap after jQuery ajax call?
- Something else?

I am using angularJS v1.2.23, ui-router v0.2.10.

Looking for a sexy angular solution.

Comment: To make something available in all controllers, you could use a service. Otherwise using the rootScope will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a data share problem and it has many sides to take into consideration.

**One solution** would be to place the "items" in $scope of the mainCtrl. In this case, all the child controllers **scopes** will **inherit** from mainCtrl scope and will therefore have access to "$scope.items" inside their own scope. The downside of this way of doing things is the pollution of the scopes and possible overriding by mistake - I would use it for appConfig or stuff like that, but not anything else.

**The 2nd solution** is to have some **data managers** services which are responsible of fetching data - in these data managers you could cache the responses and return them directly on 2nd call (this has it's own risk in terms of data volatility, depends on the case). You can "know" in a controller of a data manager managed to fetch some data if you return a promise for each GET method and in controllers you just wait for that promise to resolve on the .then() case.

**The 3rd solution** would be via **events**. The ctrl that is responsible of fetching that specific data type will fetch the data and when that is ready it will raise an event (e.g. "initDataReady") that will be cought by the other ctrls/etc.

In terms of templates, you can always put some ng-if="myModel.items !== null" and content will not be displayed while the items are being loaded. You can even put a  as well (to show a loading indicator).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but will probably just call/check resource on every view request and update accordingly.

Comment: That might cause a lot of overhead if items are not cached. And again, I don't know if you want to cache everything...

Answer (score 0):

After some work with Angular (its awesome by the way), I have come to use the following structure to ensure data availability and application flow with router-ui and its state resolve property.

http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-application-wide-resources-centrally-in-angularjs-with-ui-router/

And with $cacheFactory store top required results.

Nested views also ease use of transitions ([animate css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)) on level navigating.

Note: resolved resource function require String dependencies for minimization (ngAnnotate).

```
resolve:{
            MyServivce: 'MyService',
            item: ['MyService', function(MyService){
                   MyService.doSomething().$promise;
            }]
}
```

*(writing this angular was 1.3.0)*